# API service complains HTTPS requests are missing username and password

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient, .net-5

I'm having some trouble making HTTPS requests to an API service. I get occasional 401 (Unauthorized) errors.

When I complain to the people providing the API service, they said:

> We're seeing an occurrence where the username and password isn't being sent as part of the requests that fail the 401.  Please confirm you are still sending the username and password.

My API is called from a class, which has this code in the constructor.

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new(Settings.Username, Settings.Password);
HttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
HttpClient = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler);
```

And then it executes the following code any number of times.

```
string response = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(GetApiUrl(path, equipmentId));
```

I question if they are correct. The errors are random. If I wasn't providing the credentials, then it should fail every time.

Can anyone see any problems with my code? Or any my code could send a request that was missing the username and password?

Comment: Is this the only instance of the `HttpClient` class in your code?

Comment: @derpirscher: I believe it's the only one while the instance of this class exists.

Comment: Have you checked the `DefaultRequestHeaders` *before* sending the request, it should have an `Authorization` header with your credentials.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that call and hover over `HttpClient`, find the `DefaultRequestHeaders` and then `Authorization`, does it have your information?

Comment: are in control of the API side? can you look at the headers being actually sent?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro: I do not control the API side. This is just what they are telling me.

Comment: @zaggler: No, it looks like it is null. Not sure why though.

Comment: @JonathanWood that's the issue, you'll need to add the `Authorization` header. Can you tell us what API?

Comment: Do you know if the api uses Basic Authentication? because it might be a different thing.  Without knowing the specs for the security on the API and seeing the headers it is difficult to know what you need to send

Comment: @JonathanWood try `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(Settings.Username, Settings.Password);` *before* you make that request. Then inspect again, are they there? If that doesn't work, try, `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{Settings.Username}:{Settings.Password}")));`. Again, not sure if they need to be encrypted or not, basic doesn't provide that.

Comment: @zaggler: Yes, in that case the authorization object is there. But this is confusing because this property is never not null unless I use the code you provided, but the API doesn't fail every time.

Comment: Looking at your code, are you disposing the `HttpClient` when you're done with it and or the class, are you re-using those objects?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro: I do not know what authentication they are using. I only know that my code usually works, which suggested to me that I was passing the right information.

Comment: @zaggler: No, not explicitly. And I was thinking I might rework that so it does. However, this is a cron job and it only runs once and then the application terminates. I'm going to implement `IDisposable` in my class, but don't see how that will change the credentials.

Comment: Interesting, I would put some logging in to write out your headers before making the call. Then if and when it happens again you'll have a log to confirm *if* it's your end.

Comment: @zaggler: Yes, I will try something like that. However, it appears the Authorization property is always null.

Comment: @JonathanWood it shouldn't be if they require credentials to validate the user and they should be part of the header specifically in the `Authorization` part. It very well could be there end as well. First, make sure it's not your request that is the actual issue.

Comment: @JonathanWood another option to check is the `ClientCertificateOption` that is on `HttpClientHandler`. Inspect this before making your request, it should be `ClientCertificateOption.Automatic` as it's required to even send the `Credentials` you set for the handler.

Comment: @zaggler: It's manual by default. I will play with it set at automatic. But, again, I don't understand how this ever worked if I have it wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWood any updates on this issue?

Comment: @zaggler: Still unresolved but it seems that the service cannot handle being called from multiple threads. It seems to work if I just make one request at a time. They said I'm not authenticating correctly but the fact that it works one at a time makes me think they are just wrong.